# Includes Method isn't detecting existing item in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove an object from an array if the object exists already in the array. I know how to remove the object but I'm using the `includes()` method to find out if the object exists. I can't seem to get this working properly. Here's some code:

```js
const sampleRange = [{from: 500, to: 600}, {from: 700, to: 800}]

const objectFromRange = sampleRange[0]

const objectRange = {from: 500, to: 600}

sampleRange.includes(objectFromRange) => true

sampleRange.includes(objectRange) => false
```

So why does one sampleRange.includes come out to `true` rather the other one comes out as `false`? They're the same object.

Comment: Try this in your console: `objectRange === objectFromRange`.

Comment: `console.log( {} == {} )` // false ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because object variables are references to a place in memory. This is the reason that `objectFromRange` works but `objectRange` doesnt. `objectFromRange`references a place in memory that is inside the array while `objectRange` does not. To do what you want to do use `Array.some()`

`sampleRange.some((range)=>range.from == 500 && range.to == 600)`

Comment: "It is because object variables are references to a place in memory." This is also true in other languages, but Python in particular, implements equality comparison by the contents rather than just its address. So the other half of the answer is to explain how equality comparison works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`const objectRange = {from: 500, to: 600}` at this line you have created new instance of object, it is not the same object as it is in array